# Search by prefix on concatenation of fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Did not find an answer for this on Google.

I have json objects, which contains `first_name` and `last_name`.

I want to run search that will match if the query is prefix of `first_name + last_name` or `last_name + first_name`.

E.g. for objects:

```
{
     "first_name":"Leo",
     "last_name": "messi"
}
{
     "first_name":"Leo",
     "last_name": "Cohen"
}
```

- leo -> should match both
- leo m-> should match the first one
- messi l-> should match the first one
- le -> should match both
- co -> should match the second one

Comment: You will almost certainly need to combine those fields into a single field to get the exact behavior you're after; ES doesn't offer any facility to combine fields in a defined order on the fly for searching. They need to be combined at index time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do this with a cross-field search.

See: 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cross_fields_queries.html

Comment: from what I've seen cross_fields do the search for each field separately, but does not do the concatenation.